# QGIS/JOSM/GOOGLE MAP API : A way to filter(Highway=street_light) and save it in CSV file

Tags: java, openstreetmap, google-maps-api-2, qgis, overpass-api

I need to use open street map data, specifically the street light (highway=street_light or street_lamp or lit=*) data and save it in a CSV file.

I can see the street lights in JOSM but I can't find a way to filter only the these 'highway' values, from the many tags displayed over a selected area, and save it in a CSV.

I used QGIS also and although there is an option to filter the tags I don't want, I can't see street_lights in it. 
The value for the tag 'highway' displayed here is 'traffic_light'. 
Is there any way to get what I want?
Also, I need the node(lat, long) of every light. Please suggest.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Overpass API](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Overpass_API) to query OpenStreetMap for `highway=street_lamp` nodes. Overpass API is able to return [CSV](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Overpass_API/Overpass_QL#Output_Format_.28out:.29):

```
[out:csv(::id,::lat,::lon)][timeout:25];
node["highway"="street_lamp"]({{bbox}});
out;
```

See an [example at overpass turbo](https://overpass-turbo.eu/s/EhO).